# Default icons I can use in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview

I want to have a list and in each item I want to have a small icon that signifies success/failure.
Is there anything build-in to android e.g. default icons that I can use to display that?
I assume I need to declare an ImageView and as `android:src` add some image that is part of the installation?
How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay...You can get a set of Material Design Icons pack,all you have to do is install this plugin Android Material Design Icon Generator

MAC:

> Preference > Plugins > Browse repositories, then search material.

Linux or Windows:

> File > Settings... > IDE Settings > Plugins > Browse repositories,
>   then search material.

After installing restart your IDE and right click on your drawable folder
select New->Material design icon

Comment: Is this for Android Studio? That is what I am using

Comment: Yup.I am using this for Android Studio

Answer (score 4):

Use `android:src="@android:drawable/btn_plus"`

but I don't think it's a good way, it would be better for you to copy the images to your drawables folder, even the documenation says so it advises not to use any icon directly from android.R.drawable

say for example, you are using btn_plus icon provided by the android.R.drawable and in near future say in API 25 they stop using btn_plus, your application may crash.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can use android icon whith this code:

```
            imgView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_myplaces);
```

In fact, these icons are on the path android.R.drawable.icons and try to find your Favorite Icons

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
android.R.drawable.xxx
```

(use autocomplete to see whats in there)

Use [this](https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html) link to donwload the icons.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use android default icon in your application

```
imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);
```

Also you can check in Android SDK for different icons with below path

**android-sdk/platforms/android-19/data/res/**